# How can I call this template function correctly in main() in cpp which uses chrono library to convert a number to a date?

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

How can I call this template function correctly in main() in cpp which uses chrono library to convert a number to a date?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <chrono>
 #include <tuple>
 
 //using namespace std;
 // Returns year/month/day triple in civil calendar
 // Preconditions:  z is number of days since 1970-01-01 and is in the range:
 //                   [numeric_limits<Int>::min(), numeric_limits<Int>::max()-719468].
 template <class Int>
 constexpr
 std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>
 civil_from_days(Int z) noexcept
 {
     static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
              "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
     static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
              "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
     z += 719468;
     const Int era = (z >= 0 ? z : z - 146096) / 146097;
     const unsigned doe = static_cast<unsigned>(z - era * 146097);          // [0, 146096]
     const unsigned yoe = (doe - doe/1460 + doe/36524 - doe/146096) / 365;  // [0, 399]
     const Int y = static_cast<Int>(yoe) + era * 400;
     const unsigned doy = doe - (365*yoe + yoe/4 - yoe/100);                // [0, 365]
     const unsigned mp = (5*doy + 2)/153;                                   // [0, 11]
     const unsigned d = doy - (153*mp+2)/5 + 1;                             // [1, 31]
     const unsigned m = mp < 10 ? mp+3 : mp-9;                            // [1, 12]
     return std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>(y + (m <= 2), m, d);
 }
 
 
 int main(){
    std::cout<< civil_from_days(15432)<<'\n';
 }
```

which gives [this](https://dpaste.com/8WAZY52YS) or [this (the same)](https://pastebin.com/bCdawxVx) compiler errors.

The code is from [Howard Hinnant](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You are already calling the function in main in `std::cout<< civil_from_days(15432)<<'\n';`

Comment: Are you asking how to access the value that is returned from the function?

Comment: please include compiler errors in the question. The issue is not calling the function, but how you try to print the returned value. The actual question seems to be: "How to print a tuple?"

Comment: @NathanOliver yes.

Comment: What is purpose to `std::tuple` in c++? Store arbitrary set of data in templeted code. Use of tuple in none templete code makes code harder to read and maintain. Using indexes of tuple is also bug-prone. You should just define a structure with well named field names and return this struct (tuple is a struct, but fields do not have well defined names). At least in my project such return type is rejected during code review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to the function is not the problem. The error you get (which you should have included in the question) is because there is no predefined output operator for tuples. Though, you can print the individual members:

```
int main(){
    auto res = civil_from_days(15432);
    std::cout<< std::get<0>(res)<<'\n';
    std::cout<< std::get<1>(res)<<'\n';
    std::cout<< std::get<2>(res)<<'\n';
 }
```

Comment: In C++17 and later, here is another way to call it: `auto [y, m, d] = civil_from_days(15432);`.